# How do I accumulate a user-defined ufunc in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

How do I get accumulate working with use-defined ufuncs?

```py
import numpy as np

def leak(x, jump):
   return x * 0.9 + jump
 
leaku = np.frompyfunc(leak, 2, 1)
leaku.accumulate(np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.0]))  # ideally [0, 1.0, 1.9, 1.9*0.9, etc.]
```

produces

```
ValueError: could not find a matching type for leak (vectorized).accumulate, requested type has type code 'd'
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DaniMesejo This doesn't work, but I'd like it to work

Comment: We want to see what's wrong.  **doesn't work** is not enough.

Comment: @hpaulj updated, as requested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`numpy.frompyfunc` [can only produce](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html) ufuncs with object dtype output, but `ufunc.accumulate` [defaults](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) to using the input dtype as the dtype for intermediate results. (That, or the dtype of the `out` array if you provide one, but you didn't provide one.) When you pass in an array of float64 dtype, `ufunc.accumulate` looks for a ufunc loop with float64 output, and it doesn't find one.

You can pass in an array of object dtype, like `np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.0], dtype=np.object_)`, or you can override the default intermediate dtype with `leaku.accumulate(np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.0]), dtype=np.object_)`.

Note that `numpy.frompyfunc` ufuncs are as slow as any other Python-level code, not "NumPy speed", and object arrays have much worse speed and memory characteristics than normal arrays, as well as other inconvenient behavior. I wouldn't recommend using `numpy.frompyfunc`. Consider using Numba instead.

Comment: `itertools.accumulate` is faster, especially if given a list rather than an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
result = leaku.accumulate(np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.0]), dtype=np.object).astype(np.float)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[0.     1.     1.9    1.71   1.539  1.3851]
```