# How to Rolling Add The Previous Data With Percentage

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to do a calculation where the previous data is percentage added
a dataframe like this :

```
a = 100
```

with a growth of 10% growth where previously added to be like this :

```
df = [110,121,133.10,146.41]
```

Comment: Should not be `133.10` in place of `133` in your sample data?

Comment: @ Daweo Yes, it is true,

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: What have you tried so far, with a code example? What do you expect? What error do you get? For help, take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: @albert I've tried it with a loop in pandas but it doesn't work, it's just a simple exponential growth,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataframe columns are [pandas.Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) objects which [can be converted into](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html) a [`numpy.narray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html). Therefore, you can act on the underlying array.

To implement a user-defined accumulative function representing a 10 % increase/growth, we can combine [`numpy.frompyfunc`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html) and [`numpy.ufunc.accumulate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html):

```
import numpy as np

arr = [100, 100, 100, 100, 100]

uadd = np.frompyfunc(lambda x, y: x*1.1, 2, 1)
out = uadd.accumulate(arr, dtype=object).astype(float)[1:]

print(out)
```

Printing:

```
[110.   121.   133.1  146.41]
```

*A similar approach was described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27912352/3991125) and [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64705709/3991125) which I like to mention as further references.*