# vectorize multiply-and-accumulate in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Can a simple low-pass filter algorithm of this sort be vectorized using Python numpy? I want to get the output array xLP without doing the explicit for loop.  The "multiply and accumulate" numpy answers I've found so far don't seem to directly enable this sort of calculation.

```
import numpy as np

f = 0.1  # low-pass filter fraction
elems = 10
x = np.random.randn(elems) # normal distribution
xLP = np.zeros(elems+1)  # starting point for output

for i in range(0,elems):
     xLP[i+1] = (1.0-f)*xLP[i] + f*x[i]
     
# now xLP contains a low-pass filtered version of x
```

Comment: `f * np.sum(np.power((1 - f), np.arange(i - 1, -1, -1)) * x[:i])` should give `xLP` for any `i`

Comment: I confirm that is true. I was wondering if there's a way to get the full vector xLP for all values of i, without doing the explicit for loop.

Comment: This can't be vectorized efficiently with `numpy`. A solution will be O(n^2) instead of O(n), e.g. `r = (1-f)**np.arange(elems); (np.tril(scipy.linalg.toeplitz(np.r_[0, r], r)) * x).sum(1) * f`. `numba` would compile OP's solution without any change.

Comment: Thanks for that note. I found numba (@njit decorator on a function version of above code) to speed up my function by about 60x, for a vector size of 1E7 elements.  (46.3 s without, 0.78 s with, 10 iterations on a Win10 laptop), and roughly similar speedup on a Linux system.

Comment: There are ufunc like `np.multiply.accumulate` for such a thing (only for the product here), but you want a specific ufunc that is not available in Numpy, especially since it is parametrized by `f`. As for Numba, this is indeed the best solution. Note that the loop carried dependency will cause the computation to be *latency-bound* by the latency of the FMADD instructions of the dependency chain. On Skylake, it is about 4 cycles of latency while 2 FMA instructions per cycles can be done on 4 items in a row so there is certainly a large room for improvement (x32) if you can break the chain.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom [ufunc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html) and then use [numpy.ufunc.accumulate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) to do this [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62736143/1609514).

The only catch is you have to prepend the initial value of the state variable, x0, to the input sequence, which I did using `numpy.concatenate` here:

```
f = 0.1

def fLP(x, u):
    return (1. - f) * x + f * u

fLP_ufunc = np.frompyfunc(fLP, nin=2, nout=1)

elems = 10
U = np.random.randn(elems)
xLP = fLP_ufunc.accumulate(np.concatenate([[0], U]))
print(xLP)
```

Output:

```
[0.0 0.012215536705072135 -0.10167816687137106 -0.1199850967608808
 -0.05981846281683581 -0.02892504449551806 -0.08952817494049874
 -0.2559176019185426 -0.20433416944559457 -0.20696107336969943
 -0.15984414263697735]
```

However, it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64705800/1609514) that:

> `numpy.frompyfunc` ufuncs are as slow as any other Python-level code, not "NumPy speed"